# i18n for bean validation messages

Tags: java, bean-validation

I've the following code to do bean validation:

```
ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
Set<ConstraintViolation<MyObject>> validations = validator.validate(myObject);
if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(violations)) {
    for (ConstraintViolation<?> validateError : violations) {

    }
}
```

Is there any way to get the message from standard bean-validation resource files?

I am using the following (non-standard way):

```
Messages.get(validateError.getMessageTemplate().substring(1, 
     validateError.getMessageTemplate().length() - 1),locale);
```

Comment: Is [this](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.1/reference/en-US/html/chapter-message-interpolation.html#section-message-interpolation) what you want to achieve?

Comment: `By default, the JVM's default locale (Locale#getDefault()) will be used when looking up messages in the bundle` I want to customise the language without changing the whole VM language!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to change the interpolation Locale depending on some external criteria (for example the users Locale), you can specify a custom `MessageInterpolator` when bootstrapping Bean Validation. You can either do that via XML and `validation.xml` or programmatically like so:

```
ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = Validation.byDefaultProvider()
        .configure()
        .messageInterpolator( new MyMessageInterpolator() )
        .buildValidatorFactory();
Validator validator = validatorFactory.getValidator();
```

In `MyMessageInterpolator` you can then for example retrieve the (users) Locale via  `ThreadLocal`. You can then pass the actual validation to the default message interpolator (accessible via Configuration#getDefaultMessageInterpolator() during bootstrapping) using the interpolate method of `MessageInterpolator` which takes an explicit `Locale` instance:

```
public String interpolate(String messageTemplate, Context context, Locale locale)
```